# Android: turn off display without destroying or pausing activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile

i have a mediaplayer in an activity, i want to implement a feature in which when a user clicks a button, the screen display goes off, but the video continues to play in that activity.

Comment: What's your question? Please show what you have tried so far. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Acording to the life cycle of the Android activity, when an activity becomes background, onPause is called, however, from now on, the system can kill the activity by its will, ie. the system requires more memory.
It'S the system that decides to kill the activity or not, not the developers. In general, It'S because more memory are needed.

[Understand the Lifecycle Callbacks](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a Service. Start at this link on how to do it: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#mpandservices

Answer (score 0):

1. activity should be paused
2. you can override the procedure `onPause()` and `onResume()` to check the event
3. when pause, you pause the media, when resume you resume the media
4. the media is playing the other thread and draw the activity. when the activity is pause, but the media thread is working.